# How to run Macbook Pro retina on native resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have Macbook Pro 13.3 inches Retina display model. The max resolution am able to use is 1440X900. And default is even less. Why Macbook pro retina doesn't work in the native resolution?

Is there any specific reason for the same?

Comment: What do you mean by native ?

Comment: 13.3-inch (2560 x 1600)

Comment: I think that is just a compromise between the screen capacities and the apple graphic rendering standards...